# Click Accuracy of this code must be less than 5 milliseconds But why not?

Tags: click, setinterval

Click Accuracy of this code must be less than 5 milliseconds
But why not?
i cant understand why consule result is forexample -16 !
can anybody suggest a better for this goal or correct that? please

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-default-medium x-rtl')
var targetBtn;
for (let i =0 ; i< btns.length; i++) 
{
    if(btns[i].innerText === 'ok') 
    {
        targetBtn = btns[i];
    }
}
var    target = new Date();

target.setHours(10);
target.setMinutes(29);
target.setSeconds(59);
target.setMilliseconds(980); 

setInterval(func, 5);
function func() 
{
    var jnow = new Date();      //get current time
    var diff = (target-jnow);   // result in milisecond
    if(diff <= 0 &&  diff > -500) 
    {
        targetBtn.click();
        //alert(diff);
        console.log(diff);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduced time precision has been introduced in browsers to prevent tracking users based on the speed at which their browser responds to millisecond timing requests.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Essentially a browser can track a user that does not want to be tracked by checking how fast their computer is. So web browser makers now round the time.

Comment: thank u. i think my answer is workers. how can i use workers in console ?